# Bunching a group of notifications

Tags: php, mysql, notifications, grouping

I have a `notifications` table with me:

```
+----+------+--------+--------+------------+
| ID | User | Object | Action | TimeStamp  |
+----+------+--------+--------+------------+
|  1 |    1 |      3 | Like   | 2014-05-01 |
|  2 |    2 |      3 | Like   | 2014-05-01 |
|  3 |    3 |      3 | Like   | 2014-05-01 |
|  4 |    3 |      5 | Share  | 2014-05-01 |
+----+------+--------+--------+------------+
```

If you can see, the Users `1`, `2`, `3` have liked the same object `3`. In the Notifications window, if we just give a simple `SELECT` query, it shows like this:

- User `1` has liked Object `3`. *2 mins ago*
- User `2` has liked Object `3`. *2 mins ago*
- User `3` has liked Object `3`. *2 mins ago*
- User `3` has shared Object `5`. *2 mins ago*

But since the action has been done on the same object, I would like to bunch or group the notifications like this:

- Users `1`, `2`, `3` has liked Object `3`. *2 mins ago*
- User `3` has shared Object `5`. *2 mins ago*

I have the following questions:

1. How do I group / bunch the notifications?
2. Is my `notifications` table schema the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select object, action, group_concat(`user`) as users
from notifications
group by object, action
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there's a `Share` in the middle!